# In `go test`, is it possible to pass custom flags?

Tags: go, go-testing

As far as I tested, `go test -- <custom flag(s)>` works but I couldn't find any documentation for it.

---

I have this test code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"
)

var isVerbose = false

func init() {
    for _, flag := range os.Args {
        if flag == "-my-verbose" {
            isVerbose = true
        }
    }
}

func Test_1(t *testing.T) {
    if isVerbose {
        t.Log("hello")
    }
    t.Log("world")
}
```

The output is this:

```bash
$ go test . -v
=== RUN   Test_1
    main_test.go:22: world
--- PASS: Test_1 (0.00s)
PASS
ok      a   0.137s
```

```bash
$ go test . -v -- -my-verbose
=== RUN   Test_1
    main_test.go:20: hello
    main_test.go:22: world
--- PASS: Test_1 (0.00s)
PASS
ok      a   0.140s
```

Is this `-- <custom flag(s)>` syntax guaranteed to work always? I `grep`ed `go help build`, `go help test` and `go help testflag` to find the string `--` to no avail.

Comment: Have you seen what is in Args?

Comment: @DanielA.White `[<temp dir>/a.test -test.paniconexit0 -test.timeout=10m0s -test.v=true -- -my-verbose]`

Comment: So there nothing special about it hence no documentation

Comment: @DanielA.White No. There *is* a special behavior. If you omit `--`, `go test` fails: `flag provided but not defined: -my-verbose`, meaning `--` has a special meaning.

Comment: The `—`terminator is [documented](https://pkg.go.dev/flag): _Flag parsing stops just before the first non-flag argument ("-" is a non-flag argument) or after the terminator "--"._

Comment: @JimB And the source code of `go` command uses `flag` package: [source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/main.go#L11). These explain why `-- <flag(s)>` works (in implementation level though). Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

While it might not be documented, the `--` delimiter to pass custom flags to test commands in Go is a pretty standard practice.

In your case, `go test . -v -- -my-verbose` works because anything after `--` is treated as arguments to the test binary, rather than options to go test. So, your test binary (main_test.go in this case) can interpret `-my-verbose` as a custom flag.